# React Context API with Typescript Generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type ContextProps<T = object> = {
  store: T,
  updateStore: React.Dispatch<T>
};

export default React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({}); // is there any way to pass the generic? so store can correct type

export function Provider<T, K>(props: T & { store: K }) {
  const [globalState, updateStore] = React.useState(props.store);
  const value = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      store: globalState,
      updateStore,
    }),
    [globalState],
  );

  return <StateMachineContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
}
```

Is there any way to pass generic into Context, so `value` can have the correct type?

Comment: The only way I can semi achieve what you are asking is to type it on the other end when you call `useContext<Type>(Context);`. I think this is the best you are going to get as components making use of your context could appear under any instance of a provider for the context and each of these providers could have different generic types meaning typescript can't infer generic types for the consumer as it would have to assume the location of the component in the react tree. This is my understanding of it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for sharing solution @JacobSmit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pass the type when creating the context, remember to create it outside the components.

```
type ContextProps<T = object> = {
  store: T,
  updateStore: React.Dispatch<T>
};

function createGenericContext<T extends object> () {
  return React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps<T>>>({}); 
}

const StateMachineContext = createGenericContext<{type: 'a'}>();
// or just
const StateMachineContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps<{type: 'a'}>>>({});

export function Provider<T, K>(props: T & { store: K }) {
  const [globalState, updateStore] = React.useState(props.store);
  const value = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      store: globalState,
      updateStore,
    }),
    [globalState],
  );

  return <StateMachineContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: im getting:  Type 'K' is not assignable to type '{ type: "a"; } | undefined'.